# Which of the languages does Python resemble in its class syntax?

Tags: .net, python

I want to start programming in python and I was wondering,
which languages does Python resemble in syntax? I am familiar with .net.

Comment: I don't think it resembles any .NET language. Except maybe IronPython.

Comment: Python only resembles Python. :)

Comment: None at all, or all OO languages, depending on how you see it. it's kind of an open-ended questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

None, really. Python syntax is kind of unique.

ie ( taken from: [Python tutorial - classes](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html) )

```
>>> class Complex:
...     def __init__(self, realpart, imagpart):
...         self.r = realpart
...         self.i = imagpart
...
>>> x = Complex(3.0, -4.5)
>>> x.r, x.i
(3.0, -4.5)
```

It was heavily inspired in a language called ABC, but nowadays it's easier to learn Python than ABC.

See also:  [Python Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29#History)

Answer (score 4):

Python's abstract syntax is heavily inspired by C, as is its concrete micro-syntax. Its concrete macro-syntax, though is fairly different from C, since it uses indentation and dedentation to delimit blocks, similar to Haskell, F#, ISWIM and a couple of others.

Semantically, Python is probably closer to something like Modula-2 with objects, but dynamically typed, of course.

Comment: I personally like this answer best, because I think it is the most accurate, but I think a lot of people will not be familiar with those terms and the other languages mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

The only language I can think of that looks like Python today is Ruby, but Ruby was actually influenced by Python. It doesn't really look like anything you've ever used in .NET unless you used IronPython or IronRuby.

Don't let that discourage you, Python is very simple to learn and most of the syntax (e.g. operators) won't confuse you.

Comment: Ruby was not particularly influenced by Python. At least not the basic syntax and semantics. In fact, Matz didn't know Python when he designed Ruby and he has said that if he *had* known Python he probably wouldn't even have created Ruby and just used Python instead. Much later, there were some features of Ruby that were inspired by some features of Python, but that was long after the syntax and basic semantics were designed.

Comment: The syntax for function declaration and class declaration is very similar.

Comment: @Jorg He wanted a language "more powerful than Perl and more object-oriented than Python." Some of the language is directly influenced by Python, and basic Ruby programs are readily understood by Python programmers (and vice versa).

Answer (score 1):

It's mostly its own thing. The biggest change relative to most languages is that indentaton is significant. For example the function definition

```
def func():
    print "hello",
    print "world"
```

relies on the indentation of the two 'print' statements to define the boundaries of the function. All blocks are specified in this way - if statements and so on.

As far as classes go, they're pretty much like you'd expect - except that the pointer to the current object is made explicit as the first argument to the function

```
class myclass:
    def classassign(self, string):
        self.mystr=string
    def classprint(self):
        print self.mystr

obj=myclass()
obj.classassign("class var")
obj.classprint()
```

prints

> class var

Personally, Python isn't much like any other languages I know - which iis why it's a lot of fun. if that simple class looks like something you're familiar with, there you go. But I recommend a good book on Python since the "Pythonic" way of doing things is probably very different from what you expect